# Refreshing composer/airflow DAG in order to generate task list dynamically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

Team, I have a single DAG which has YML file name as input from airflow variable. Based on YML file DAG generates tasks list dynamically. When I am changing YML file name in airflow variable name, it's not getting reflecting it in DAG. I clicked on refresh DAG that also didn't work. Can someone please help on this? I want this DAG as generic DAG which can work based on input YML. Is there any CLI command which can be used to get DAG updated?

FYI Another DAG works if I hardcode name of the YML file name and its getting rendered properly and shows all task generated. But I want to make it generic based on YML file.

Answer (score 1):

I tried replicating the issue at my end and it’s working for me. Since you want this DAG as a generic DAG which can work based on an input YML, you can use the open source Python library [dag-factory](https://github.com/ajbosco/dag-factory) for that.

These are the steps that I followed to implement your requirement:

1. Add the “dag-factory” library in the PyPi packages in the Composer environment.
2. Create 2 sample YML DAG definition files (example_dag1.yml and example_dag2.yml) to test the setup.
3. Put these YML files in the “data” folder in the GCS bucket in the Composer environment.
4. Create the DAG file and put it in the “dags” folder in the GCS bucket.
   In the Airflow UI, add a variable with “yml_file” as the key and “example_dag1.yml” as the value.
5. You can then change the file name in the variable to check if the DAG gets updated.

The DAG file and the sample YML files are as shown below.

**dag.py**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
import dagfactory

file_name = Variable.get("yml_file")
file_path = "/home/airflow/gcs/data/" + str(file_name)
dag_factory = dagfactory.DagFactory(file_path)

dag_factory.clean_dags(globals())
dag_factory.generate_dags(globals())
```

**example_dag1.yml (3 tasks)**

```
example_dag1:
  default_args:
    owner: 'example_owner'
    start_date: 2018-01-01  # or '2 days'
    end_date: 2021-10-10
    retries: 1
    retry_delay_sec: 300
  schedule_interval: '0 3 * * *'
  concurrency: 1
  max_active_runs: 1
  dagrun_timeout_sec: 60
  default_view: 'tree'  # or 'graph', 'duration', 'gantt', 'landing_times'
  orientation: 'LR'  # or 'TB', 'RL', 'BT'
  description: 'this is an example dag!'
  tasks:
    task_1:
      operator: airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator
      bash_command: 'echo 1'
    task_2:
      operator: airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator
      bash_command: 'echo 2'
      dependencies: [task_1]
    task_3:
      operator: airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator
      bash_command: 'echo 3'
      dependencies: [task_1]
```

**example_dag2.yml (5 tasks)**

```
example_dag1:
  default_args:
    owner: 'example_owner'
    start_date: 2018-01-01  # or '2 days'
    end_date: 2021-10-10
    retries: 1
    retry_delay_sec: 300
  schedule_interval: '0 3 * * *'
  concurrency: 1
  max_active_runs: 1
  dagrun_timeout_sec: 60
  default_view: 'tree'  # or 'graph', 'duration', 'gantt', 'landing_times'
  orientation: 'LR'  # or 'TB', 'RL', 'BT'
  description: 'this is an example dag!'
  tasks:
    task_1:
      operator: airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator
      bash_command: 'echo 1'
    task_2:
      operator: airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator
      bash_command: 'echo 2'
      dependencies: [task_1]
    task_3:
      operator: airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator
      bash_command: 'echo 3'
      dependencies: [task_1]
    task_4:
      operator: airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator
      bash_command: 'echo 4'
      dependencies: [task_2]
    task_5:
      operator: airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator
      bash_command: 'echo 5'
      dependencies: [task_3]
```